# How do I use Web API 2 and bearer tokens and my own user table while persisting the userid to the users records

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

My legacy web forms app uses windows authentication to match up the incoming user domain\username against a custom user table. If they are registered the user Id is stored in a session variable and whenever a new shipment record is created by the user the shipment record is created with the session.userID (foreign key to the user table.)

In a nutshell mu criteria is:

1. Use windows authentication (no typing passwords)
2. Use bearer token's.
3. Persist the user id (primary key) from custom table to track user records etc..
4. Use Web api
5. Use EF 6

I would like to build a new Angular front end with web api 2.0 Entity Framework 6 but continue using my own user table rather that the new asp.net.Identity.

The main criteria for this intranet application was people didn't want to have to type user names and passwords, they wanted to just authenticate by the windows account. I cannot see any example of how to do this with Web API and bearer token. All examples are based around the Asp.net.Identity

I was planning on using vs2013 Webapi with the Windows Authentication Template but I am lost and cannot see any example's for Intranet apps where people do this.

I really like the idea of bearer token's and want to use then but with my own user table whilst ensuring that my user.id is used by EF when new records are created etc..

Answer (score 0):

The method of authentication is determined by the web server hosting your application, not the application itself. I have done this several times myself for production-level Intranet business web applications. The setting(s) that make this happen is located in your application's `web.config` file. Get to know the settings in that file very well. *It's important*.

There are two terms to keep in mind and both have different meanings: user authentication and user authorization. You don't need some fancy framework to accomplish user authentication, given your requirements. Since you are relying on Windows Authentication against Active Directory, anyone who isn't on your company's domain won't be able to access the website, period. The authentication is handled automatically for you by the server (IIS, I assume). It's super simple. When you provision the site under IIS, just make sure that Windows Authentication is the only enabled form of authentication.

User authorization can be more granular. Even though a user may be authenticated, you still may not want them to have access. This is where your user table comes in to play. The process is rather straightforward. Once the user is authenticated by the server, the server stores their credentials into the `User.Identity` variable that you can access in your server-side code. You could then verify that the `User.Identity.Name` is in your table and generate a verification token or cookie to store on the client. In the same action, you could also send to the client the user's id. I'd store the token and the user id either in the client's `sessionStorage` or as a cookie. Then, for security protection, you could send this token on every server request. As long as the token is valid, the HTTP action is processed. Furthermore, when the user makes a PUT, POST or DELETE, include the user id in the request data.

Here are some helpful links:

[Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

[Integrated Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication)

[Web API Security](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=dominick-baier&name=webapi-v2-security-m3-architecture&mode=live&clip=0&course=webapi-v2-security)

Comment: Hi Brett thanks for responding, I'm ok with windows authentication and detecting the user from a web api controller. Can you show my how to lookup the user and issue a token (if the client redirects to a login end point) and then how to use the userid from the token when updating creating a shipment record. from what I have read Token's are used in angular clients but they seem heavily coupled with windows Identity 2.0 which I don't want to use, Many thanks!